# Apply a property on selector using ngif angular 2

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

I have a component whose selector name is `inputTextBox`. `ie.onClick` refers to a json value which contains the function name. this function will be called when `inputClick` event occurs.

The problem is if I dont pass anything in `ie.onClick` it gives an error.

Is there any way to check if `ie.onClick` contains any value then only `(inputClick) = this[ie.onClick]()` should be place in selector. I thought of ngIf. but not sure how to use it.

Any Help?

```
<inputTextBox (inputClick) = this[ie.onClick]()></inputTextBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add ngIf directive to check the values:
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgIf-directive.html

```
<div *ngIf="ie && ie.onClick">...</div>
```

Comment: And you can trigger your onClick function using (click) directive.

Comment: I think this will only check if ie.onClick has any value or not. The question is how would I apply the statement if ie.onClick has any value.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check in the function invocation itself

```
function onClick(){
if(params)
 //do stuff
 else
 //dont execute
}
```

Comment: OnClick is not a function. It is a variable which contains the function name.

Comment: so inside the function which is denoted by that variable name , you can check the params :)